# psycopg2 named cursor withhold=True

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I am using a named cursor to fetch 200K+ rows, and using the attribute, 'withhold=True', this way I can iterate by fetching many (50K) at a time - but my cursor is not persisting...

Here is the error / stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/code/etl/etl.py", line 179, in main
    _pg_data = _fetch(_some)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: named cursor isn't valid anymore

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/code/etl/etl.py", line 330, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/me/code/etl/etl.py", line 271, in main
    logging.error(Fore.LIGHTRED_EX + e + Fore.RESET, exc_info=True)
TypeError: must be str, not ProgrammingError
```

Here is my code

```
from colorama import Fore
from datetime import datetime
import argparse, logging, psycopg2, pyodbc, sys, time, yaml
import _classes.Utils as cpu

def main():
    _cfg_path = "/home/me/code/etl/db.yml"

    with open(_cfg_path, 'r') as _ymlfile:
        _cfg = yaml.load(_ymlfile, Loader=yaml.CLoader)

    # create a connection to the database
        _conn = psycopg2.connect("host={0} dbname={1} user={2} password={3} port={4}".format(_cfg['local_postgres']['host'], _cfg['local_postgres']['db'],
                                                                                          _cfg['local_postgres']['user'], _cfg['local_postgres']['passwd'],
                                                                                             _cfg['local_postgres']['port']))

    _curs_pgsql = _conn.cursor()
    _curs_pgsql.callproc('usp_outbound', ['curs'])
    _curs2_pgsql = _conn.cursor('curs', withhold=True)

    _push_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    _some = 50000
    _fetch = _curs2_pgsql.fetchmany
    while True:
        _pg_data = _fetch(_some)
        if not _pg_data:
            break
        for _row in _pg_data:
            _params = ()
            _sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.tbl VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
            _params = (_row[0], _row[1], _row[2])
            # ...insert into destination database

            # ...now update source database and set the push and push date flags
            _curs_pgsql.execute("UPDATE products SET pushed = TRUE, pushed_date = (%s) WHERE id = (%s)", (_push_date, _row[2],))
            _conn.commit()

    if _conn:
        # close cursor / close the communication with the PostgreSQL database server
        _curs2_pgsql.close()
        _curs_pgsql.close()
        _conn.close()
```

Clearly I am missing something with my named cursor and how it's supposed to be defined...

According to the documentation -

> Set the value before calling execute() or use the connection.cursor() withhold parameter, otherwise the value will have no effect.

... ... ...

> Trying to fetch from a named cursor after a commit() or to create a named cursor when the connection is in autocommit mode will result in an exception. It is possible to create a WITH HOLD cursor by specifying a True value for the withhold parameter to cursor() or by setting the withhold attribute to True before calling execute() on the cursor.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The code seems reasonable. It's hard to say what the stored procedure (`usp_outbound`) might be doing though. Your named cursor is being created after the procedure - is that creating it? Is something happening there that might close it? Perhaps the stored procedure needs a `WITH HOLD`?

Try reorganizing the code to something like this and see if it helps (or you get an error that provides a hint).

```
with psycopg2.connect("your_connection_string") as _conn:

    # first (unnamed) cursor
    _curs_pgsql = _conn.cursor()

    with _conn.cursor(name='curs', withhold=True) as _curs2_pgsql:
        _curs2_pgsql.itersize = 50000 # fetch rows from database in batches of this value

        _push_date = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        _curs_pgsql.callproc('usp_outbound', ['curs'])

        for _row in _curs2_pgsql:
            _sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.tbl VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
            _params = (_row[0], _row[1], _row[2])
            # ...insert into destination database

            # ...now update source database and set the push and push date flags
            _curs_pgsql.execute("UPDATE products SET pushed = TRUE, pushed_date = (%s) WHERE id = (%s)", (_push_date, _row[2],))

# if there are no errors, connection will automatically
# commit() here at end of with block (but remain open)

_conn.close()
```